# How to compare multiple values in a cell with a table of data

Tags: microsoft-excel

There's PERSON NAME column, where a list of names are stored in one cell, and there are several cells.

There's ACTIVE USER LIST column, which is a basic single column table showing all the active users.

The outcome I want is as shown in ACTIVE USER (red) column, which compares the names in the cells of PERSON NAME with the table of ACTIVE USER, and store whatever is equal (i.e if PERSON NAME is in the ACTIVE USER) in a cell as shown in red.

I tried all day yesterday with it, but I couldn't work it out, and I'd appreciate your help.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning** there is a way to solve this in Excel, however it's strongly recommended to change your data structure having only one piece of information in each cell

Here is a formula solving your problem:
`=TEXTJOIN(",", TRUE, LET(userList, FILTERXML( "<a><b>" & SUBSTITUTE(A2, ",", "</b><b>") & "</b></a>", "//b"),FILTER( userList, COUNTIF($D$2:$D$6, userList)>0)))`

note *this works only in Excel 365 versions supporting LET, FILTERXML and TEXTJOIN functions*

[image]